# Can't find pip-installed package after removing its apt-get version

Tags: python, linux, pip, conda, apt-get

1. I installed a package named *black* via apt-get
2. I removed it *(because its version is too old)*
3. I installed the package via `pip3 install black`, inside a conda enviroment *(named py38)*.
4. I try to use it, but the package can't be found.

   unless I call it via its absolute path:

```
(py38)user@comuter:~/tools$ black ..

bash: /usr/bin/black: No such file or directory

(py38)user@comuter:~/tools$ /home/user/miniconda3/envs/py38/bin/black ..
```

How could I fix it?

Comment: What does `type black` give you?

Comment: Possibly something wrong with your Conda initialization in the shell. What shell and terminal are being used? (add to question)

Answer (score 0):

I opened a new terminal today and the problem is gone.

I think @merv is right about the conda initialization thing : )

All you need to do is restart the terminal.